# .NET Core in Visual Studio 2019 - Desktop deployment options

Tags: .net-core, deployment, visual-studio-2019, desktop

I tried searching for deployment methods but the results I was seeing are way to general and meaningless to be useful. Maybe there are some keywords I am missing to find what I am searching for?

I have an .NET Core application and need to push it out to many computers throughout the organization. I also need to be able to push out updates to the application periodically.

Its my understanding that this can be done through Azure but I need to know of any locally contained options that don't rely on internet connections but would work within our local network.

What could I search for to pull up lists of products and/or solutions to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tools like Teamcity, Jenkins or Octopus. Once installed, it runs on localhost and the build definition can be created to execute periodically. Also, you will be able to add your changes incrementally while planning for new builds.

For TeamCity I recommend the following link -
[deploying .NET Core app on TeamCity](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/)

For Jenkins and Octopus I came across following -
[deployment using Jenkins](https://medium.com/faun/jenkins-ci-cd-to-deploy-an-asp-net-core-application-6145b5308bff)

[deployment using Octopus and Jenkins](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploy-aspnetcore-app/to-iis/using-octopus-onprem-jenkins-builtin)